# Unable to merge dex Ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Last time I build successfully but after adding the number of pages I am unable to build, I did search for that error a lot but nothing works for me.For example, **added and removed the platform**, **ionic cordova clean** , **ionic cordova build** etc…

Following Error facing by running-- **ionic cordova build android**

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ‘**:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForD
ebug’.**
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.de
xing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

**IOnic Info:**

cli packages: (C:\Users\ITSERV\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Node : v6.11.2
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 7

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this issue by running simply this command and then build the project. don't go into complicated answers like upgrading Gradle or google packages etc..

```
 cordova clean android 
 ionic cordova build android
```

Answer (score 29):

What helped me was running:

```
cordova clean
```

Comment: That helped mee too

Comment: You're the best! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much, saved my life

Answer (score 6):

I did struggle with this issue for 2 days after i used google maps plugin inside my app and i suppose it is because of google-play-service conflicts and i resolved it by install the latest grade release by using this command. Hope it helps anyone else facing this issue

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh i will give it a try.
I am sure it is due to some plugin conflict might be facebook plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I solve with

```
Cordova Clean Android
Cordova Build Android
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue

> (Unable to merge dex Ionic)

when I created the Ionic app. When I run the app the

> BUILD FAILED in 11s
>   37 actionable tasks: 3 executed

error occurred. First I use the following solution but it doesn't work for me but it work for the other I guess.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
       force 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    } 
}
```

Finally this is what helped me to overcome the issue of failing to build the app.

```
cordova clean android
ionic cordova build android
ionic cordova run android (To re-launch the app)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issued. I solved it via two steps:

**Step 1 : cordova clean**

**Step 2: cordova build**

Answer (score 0):

Above commands didn't fix my problem.

I change the following line in project.properties in platforms folder

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1
```

to

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+
```

and it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Copying this answer from [this Github issue comment](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/issues/606#issuecomment-373283725) from [Trent Gardner](https://github.com/tgardner), since anything else didn't work for me:

> Fix for the Facebook plugin was to force the **Facebook SDK** to version **4.25.0**.
>
> ```
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-platform-replace
> ```
>
> Then add to your **config.xml**
>
> ```
> <platform name="android">
>   <replace-string file="project.properties" find="regex:com\.facebook\.android\:facebook-android-sdk\:[\+0-9\.]+" replace="com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0" />
> </platform>
> ```
>
> Finally run `cordova prepare android`
>
> Works with the latest 1.9.1 version of cordova-facebook-plugin4

Answer (score -1):

I encountered a similar problem. Installing the plugin helped me

```
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-multidex
```