# Ionic,cordova Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, ionic3, account-kit

am trying to add Facebook account kit to my project, my project has also native google map plugin when i tried to add facebook account kit plugin i got the error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430756/unable-to-merge-dex-ionic-3

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. Installing plugin `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` fixed the problem.