# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex in ionic 5

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

everyone, please help me. im running ionic cordova run android. then an error occured. before install plugin facebook4 things are going well, after instal the plugin im can not build or run android. i have running cordova clean and cordova build not solved my problem.

```
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

42 actionable tasks: 40 executed, 2 up-to-date
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 49s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: E:\PROJECT\spectraapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 49s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --device exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. iam remove plugin facebook and add again with version @1.7.4

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.7.4 --variable APP_ID="appid" --variable APP_NAME="appname"
```

add resource strings.xml in platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

```
<string name="fb_app_id">appid</string>
<string name="fb_app_name">appname</string>

ionic cordova run android
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing platform and re-add it.

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

then try 
    ionic cordova run android

If still have some issue 
[check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49430756/unable-to-merge-dex-ionic-3?rq=1)

Comment: thanks. but it isn't fix my problem. i have re-add platfrom, clean cordova, build cordova. this issue not fixed.  I have been working on fixing this issue for almost 3 days and Im getting nowhere. Ive tried everything and nothing makes a difference